# MySQL and Qt remote connection

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I am trying to develop a simple program that connects into a mysql server. Qt help is really helpfully in how to do it, but the problem in my case is that the program does not connect into a local server or a straight ip. My university provides a system for testing databases. So I have to connect first to the server, provide a password and after that connect to mysql with a different one. The problem is that i do not know how mysql works and in qt i have found out how to connect straight to the server. I do not know if this problem has a simple solution but i couldn't find anything helpful. Any help appreciated!

```
int main(){    
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db.setHostName("195.*.*.*");
    db.setPort(22);
    db.setUserName("de0338");
    db.setPassword("pass");
    db.setDatabaseName("de0338");
    bool ok = db.open();
    if(!db.open())
    {       
        qFatal("Failed to Connect");  
    }
    return ok;
}
```

Comment: First check the ``ok`` boolean, do not try to open it again, or check ``isOpen()``. Next check the error for ``db.lastError().text()``. This will probably give: ``Driver not loaded``. Then setup your driver correctly (compile yourself) and your ready to go.

Comment: Additionally check if you have libmysql.dll / libmysqlclient.so or similar client libraries in your path/beside the app

Comment: yes i will do it..But how can i provide the second password for mysql? I need to send two passwords. One for the first server of the university to connect to the system. And one for the sql.

Comment: You mqy have to setup an vpn or other or other encrypted tunneling to authenticate to the university network

Comment: I dont think that it will be something too complicated.. To understand, i connect through putty to the server. I use the ip, the 22 port. There it asks for my user name and pass. After this i connect to mysql with the usual code mysqld -u .....-p.. and i enter a different pass. My question is, how can i enter both passwords through qt? I have to use QTcpSocket or something? Or it is in QSql?

Comment: `QSqlError("2013","QMYSQL: Unable to connect", "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0 \"Internal error/check (Not system error)\"")`

Comment: This is the error from lastError()

Answer (score 0):

Try ising an ssh tunnel and then connect through this to Mysql. Managing the ssh with Qt will be difficult.